# What does 'mutual' mean in mutual fund?

Tags: mutual-funds, financial-literacy, terminology

I am confused on the usage of 'mutual'. Is there any 'mutual benefit' or 'mutual dependence' between the participants (unit holders) in a mutual fund?

It looks more like a 'mixed fund' with diverse items (securities) placed together in a single basket.

Answer (score 45):

"Mutual" as in "owned and funded by a pool of investors for a shared purpose". Some more details on the more [generic concept of a "mutual organization" can be found in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_organization). "Mutual Funds" can have other names in many different countries around the world, as is also [described in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_fund). While it is user-editable, Wikipedia can still be a useful and valuable source of information.